# In java is there a readObject() alternative for RandomAccessFile

Tags: java, file, io, save

I'm trying to save a couple of Strings but I'm currently using ObjectInputStream, which apparently doesn't save my data in a permanent manner. Here is the code which I commented in my project.  It saves the string in a temporal manner.  Anytime I exit my program, puff the data is gone:

```
ObjectInputStream FileIn= new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream("cars.txt"));

//AND HERE IS THE CODE FOR THE RandomAccessFile VERSION:
RandomAccessFile FileIn = new RandomAccessFile("cars.txt", "rw");

  au=(Cars)FileIn.readObject(); //THIS readObject(), is giving me errors
  //Cars is a Class
```

Is there any other alternative that I can use to read `RandomAccessFile`... Please help and thanks.

Comment: Are you remembering to flush and close the OutputStream before closing the application? If not then that is why the data is not being saved -- and not because of your choice of class for writing data.

Comment: Code doesn't compile. `ObjectInputStream` doesn't store objects at all, it retrieves them *from* a store. And what exactly do you mean by 'permanent manner' and 'temporal manner' and 'is giving me errors'? Question is unanswerable in its present form.

Comment: Any comment about my answer @Cesar.  Were you trying to read from random spots in a serialized output stream file?

Answer (score 1):

Just like FileInputStream, you need to wrap a RandomAccessFile in an ObjectInputStream. i.e. RandomAccessFile doesn't buy you anything.

```
final RandomAccessFile raf = new RandomAccessFile("file.dat", "r");
ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(new InputStream() {
    @Override
    public int read(byte[] b, int off, int len) throws IOException {
        return raf.read(b, off, len);
    }

    @Override
    public int read() throws IOException {
        return raf.read();
    }
});
```

Comment: Could you put it in code PLEAAAASE! it would greatly help me.. I will give you more reputation

Comment: Can't you just do a `new FileInputStream(randomAccessFile.getFD())`?

Comment: @TomHawtin-tackline, I assume this would read the file from the start. If he wants random access, he is going to need to to things differently.

Comment: @Peter Lawrey File descriptors contain offsets (slightly different for sockets and pipes, obviously). Just checked that. With either method, using `ObjectInputStream` should buffer beyond the object stream data, so the  `RandomAccessFile` after use will be "wrong".

Answer (score 0):

For simple String objects is far easier using plain DataInputStream / DataOutputStream:

```
package test;

import java.io.DataInputStream;
import java.io.DataOutputStream;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class TestFile {

    static final String FILE = "/tmp/cars.txt";

    public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
        List<String> strs = new ArrayList<String>();
        strs.add("Audi");
        strs.add("Seat");
        strs.add("Renault");

        saveStrings(strs);

        strs = loadStrings();

        System.out.println("Read strings: " + strs);

    } catch (Exception e) {

    }
    }

    static List<String> loadStrings() throws Exception {
    DataInputStream dis = null;
    List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
    try {
        dis = new DataInputStream(new FileInputStream(FILE));
        while (dis.available() > 0) {
        list.add(dis.readUTF());
        }
    } finally {
        if (dis != null)
        dis.close();
    }

    return list;
    }

    static void saveStrings(List<String> list) throws Exception {
    DataOutputStream dos = null;

    try {
        dos = new DataOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(FILE));
        for (String str : list) {
        dos.writeUTF(str);
        }
    } finally {
        if (dos != null)
        dos.close();
    }
    }

}
```

Comment: far easier, maybe, but potentially less efficient (if you are potentially storing duplicate strings).

Answer (score 0):

If you are asking whether you can use `RandomAccessFile` to seek around inside an object stream and read objects then the short answer is "no".  Serialized object streams are heavily encoded with backwards pointers to previously used objects including previously dumped class definitions, etc..

- [Serialization stream specification](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/platform/serialization/spec/protocol.html) with some format details.
- Here's some [more details on the serialization format](http://www.javaworld.com/community/node/2915).
- Discussion about [random writing from Java docs](http://java.sun.com/javase/technologies/core/basic/serializationFAQ.jsp#random).

We had a similar requirement and wrote some code which closes and re-opens the serialized stream once and a while and recorded the positions of these break points.  This didn't give us the ability to read a particular object but it did give us the ability to append to serialized stream and to skip over a particular portion of the file -- skip to the next break.

Answer (score -1):

Well you have to invoke, `writeObject()` instead of `readObject()` which is actually to read from disk to memory, and of course when the program ends, so does the memory used by that program.

Comment: No idea, upvoting. Seems OK to me!